Using Jitterbit to create Active Directory Accounts
Hello Collective Wisdom
I am looking to create User accounts in Active Directory using Jitterbit IPAAS service.
I am using the Jitterbit Scripting approach and the LDAPConnect --> LDAPAdd --> LDAP Execute pattern.
This works when setting basic attribute values, however I have had no luck adding people to security groups.
I have attempted to use the following pattern to handle a single group membership
LDAPAdd("memberof","CN=groupname,OU=Security,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=edu,DC=au") or LDAPAdd("memberof","groupname")
My understanding is that the memberof attribute in AD is a multivalued attribute and Jitterbit provides a function ArrayToMultipleValues(arr) that takes an array of values and converts them into XML.. so I have tried the following
arr = Array(); arr[Length(arr)] = "CN=groupname,OU=Security,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=edu,DC=au"; LDAPAdd("memberof",ArrayToMultipleValues(arr));
Every Approach fails with the message

Error: Invalid DN Syntax

There is no further information in the Jitterbit documentation regarding Active Directory.
If anybody has cracked this I would appreciate a solution !
Regards
Angus

Updating a group membership via attributes may be complex task. When memberof attribute is updated for a user object, there may be other attributes to be updated simultaneously like memberUID attribute or member attribute which are group attributes. When a group membership for a group is queried, this linked structure between object types (user and group) enhances performance, otherwise all the directory would have to be queried for a group membership query.
memberUID attribute (also memberof and member attributes exist near memberUID attribute)
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-ada2/b56d7327-5922-411d-8d3a-451215db2289
For instance in powershell there are different cmdlets for group management like:
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity SvcAccPSOGroup -Members SQL01, SQL02 (Taken from learn MS site.
So I think in your environment, a class related to group operations should be used instead of directly updating the object via LDAP attribute operations.
